# How to sort List<HashMap<String, String>> ls in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am in new to java and i have declared below hashMapList  list.

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> hashMapList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

I have made another method `insertData` to put the data in hashMapList.

I have also make another list `psData`.

```
HashMap<String, String> psData = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

so for insert the list in hashMapList i have use below code.

```
HashMap<String, String> psData = new HashMap<String, String>();

so for insert the list in hashMapList i have use below code.

psData = insertData(payment.getDocumentNo(), payment.getId(),
                  payment.getPaymentDate(), creditLeft, payment.getBusinessPartner(), group,
                  recOrPay.equals("RECEIVABLES") ? paymentInTab : paymentOutTab, dateFormat, true,
                  BigDecimal.ZERO, addressline1, addressline2, City, postalcode, state, email,
                  phoneno, payment.getAmount(), duration, discount,
                  payment.getFinancialTransactionAmount(), payment.getWriteoffAmount(),
                  Outstandings, Coa, Ev);
              hashMapList.add(psData);
```

Now i am want to filter that hashMapList using coa property which i have pass in insertData method.

is this possible in java ? please help me.
Thank you i have try my best but i don't understand.

```
private HashMap<String, String> insertData(String documentNo, String id, Date date,
      BigDecimal amount, BusinessPartner bpartner, int group, String tabId,
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat, boolean credits, BigDecimal doubtfulDebt, String Address1,
      String Address2, String Zip, String City, String State, String Email, String Phone_h,
      BigDecimal InvoiceAmount, int Durations, BigDecimal Discount, BigDecimal Payments,
      BigDecimal Writeoffs, BigDecimal Outstandings, String Coa, ElementValue ev) {
    HashMap<String, String> psData = new HashMap<String, String>();
    psData.put("INVOICE_NUMBER", documentNo);
    psData.put("INVOICE_ID", id);
    psData.put("INVOICE_DATE", dateFormat.format(date));
    psData.put("AMOUNT" + group, amount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 ? null : amount.toString());
    psData.put("DOUBTFUL_DEBT",
        doubtfulDebt.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 ? null : doubtfulDebt.toString());
    BigDecimal percentage = calculatePercentage(amount.add(doubtfulDebt), doubtfulDebt);
    psData.put("PERCENTAGE",
        percentage.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 ? null : percentage.toString());
    if (credits) {
      psData.put("SHOW_NETDUE", amount.add(doubtfulDebt).toString());
    } else {
      psData.put("NETDUE", amount.add(doubtfulDebt).toString());
      psData.put("SHOW_NETDUE", amount.add(doubtfulDebt).toString());
    }
    psData.put("BPARTNER", bpartner.getId().toString());
    psData.put("BPARTNERNAME", bpartner.getIdentifier().toString());
    psData.put("TABID", tabId);
    psData.put("address1", Address1);
    psData.put("address2", Address2);
    psData.put("zip", Zip);
    psData.put("city", City);
    psData.put("state", State);
    psData.put("email", Email);
    psData.put("phone_h", Phone_h);
    psData.put("invoiceamount",
        InvoiceAmount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 ? "-" : InvoiceAmount.toString());
    psData.put("durations",
        Integer.toString(Durations).equals("0") ? "-" : Integer.toString(Durations));
    psData.put("payments", Payments.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 ? "0.00" : Payments.toString());
    psData.put("writeoffs",
        Writeoffs.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 ? "0.00" : Writeoffs.toString());
    psData.put("outstandings",
        Outstandings.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 ? "0.00" : Outstandings.toString());
    psData
        .put("discounts", Discount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 ? "0.00" : Discount.toString());
    psData.put("coa", Coa);
    psData.put("ev", ev.getId());
    return psData;

  }
```

Comment: Use `Collections.sort()` along with a `Comparator<Map<String, String>>` that pulls the correct values from the maps and compares them.

Comment: @Thomas can you give me the example please

Comment: Yikes: a method with that many parameters is always dubious. For example, it is very easy to pass in two parameters in the wrong order, and you won't notice. You should consider using the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: You should also consider defining a class to hold the data in well-typed fields: a `Map` is a really sucky way to store heterogeneous data like this (i.e. you've got to make everything into a `String` to store it in your map, even though you are specifying some values as `BigDecimal` or `BusinessPartner`).

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you follow Andy Turner's suggestion as that's easier to handle and better design overall. But if you _really_ want to use a map just create a class that implements the `Comparator` interface and implement the sole declared method. The rest should be obvious (i.e. you should know how to get values from a map and compare them if they are not null - hint: `String#compareTo(...)`).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the question (not based on the title which is about sorting). You need a solution to filter your list based on the coa (chart of accounts)

Hope you are using java 8

```
        List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("prop1", "value1");
        map.put("prop2", "value2");
        map.put("coa", "value3");
        list.add(map);

        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("prop1", "value1");
        map.put("prop2", "value2");
        map.put("coa", "value3");
        list.add(map);

        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("prop1", "v1");
        map.put("prop2", "v2");
        map.put("coa", "v3");
        list.add(map);

        List<Map<String,String>> listMapWithProp3EqualValue3 = list.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.get("coa").equals("value3")).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("Filtered List with coa=value3 :" + listMapWithProp3EqualValue3);

        listMapWithProp3EqualValue3 = list.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.get("coa").equals("v3")).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("Filtered List coa=v3 :" + listMapWithProp3EqualValue3);
```

I am converting the list into stream and filtering it using lambdas.

If you are not using java 8 check the below.

[Lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)

It allows you to filter the collections.

Hope it should help you.

Comment: i have filter list using only coa all value not for particular value@Beniton

Comment: @ADMIN Sorry i did not get you. Can you give me more details? you want to filter based on all coa? which mean if it has valid coa right then you just need to check for not null.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved  my question thank you.

```
Collections.sort(hashMapList, new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {
            public int compare(HashMap<String, String> mapping1, HashMap<String, String> mapping2) {
              return mapping1.get("coa").compareTo(mapping2.get("coa"));
            }
          });
```